# Как применить псевдокласс :hover

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, вёрстка

Как применить псевдокласс `:hover` к такому классу: `header.main-header .header .social-link > li`? Пробовал вот так: `header.main-header .header .social-link > li:hover` и вот так: `.social-link > li:hover` , но не срабатывает такой класс (браузеры не видят). Подскажите пожалуйста.

html:

```
<ul class="social-link">
<li><a target="_blank" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Мы на Linked In"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
<li><a target="_blank" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Мы на Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
<li><a target="_blank" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Мы в Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter "></i></a></li>
<li><a target="_blank" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Мы в Вконтакте"><i class="fa fa-vk"></i></a></li>
<li><a target="_blank" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Мы в Google Plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
<li><a target="_blank" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Мы в Одноклассниках"><i class="fa fa-odnoklassniki"></i></a></li>
                                                                                                    </ul>
```

Comment: добавьте html разметку

Comment: @soledar10 , добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.social-link {
  text-align: center;
}
.social-link > li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 15px 0;
}
.social-link > li a {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ccc;
  transition: .3s;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
.social-link > li a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-top: 2px solid royalblue;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.social-link > li a:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: animSocialBorder 1s linear infinite;
}
.social-link > li:hover a {
  color: tomato;
}
@keyframes animSocialBorder {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="social-link">
  <li><a target="_blank" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Мы на Linked In"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Мы на Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Мы в Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter "></i></a>
  </li>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Мы в Вконтакте"><i class="fa fa-vk"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Мы в Google Plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Мы в Одноклассниках"><i class="fa fa-odnoklassniki"></i></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Мне нужно не сами ссылку поменять, мне нужно li поменять при наведении, там задан фон.